# ThreeJS issue with resizing images when they are actually as a power of 2

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've got a strange issue regarding the automatic resizing of textures by `WebGLRenderer` using threejs.

I know that WebGL requires the sizes of textures* to be the power of 2.

*-the textures that are using non-LinearFilter, or have wrapping not as a clamp set

My texture has wrap set as RepeatWrapping and the sie of the texture is 
**65536 x 512** so this is **2^16 x 2^9**

I'm assuming that the size of the texture is correct. However, the console says:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (65536x512) to (16384x128)
```

It's very bad that the texture is downsized because it's very visible on the quality of rendered texture.

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. According to the documentation, everything is set correctly.

Is there a possibility to prevent downsizing?

I don't think that's helpful but I'm also including the code of loading textures

```
const texture = new TextureLoader().load(path);
texture.anisotropy = 2;
texture.magFilter = LinearFilter;
texture.minFilter = LinearFilter;
texture.wrapS = RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set(1 / tilesAmountHorizontally, 1 / tilesAmountVertically);
```

Comment: You can't make a texture 65536 wide (or tall). The limit on your machine is clearly 16384. [Limits of various devices](https://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE). I'm guessing your next question is what to do about that. You should start a new question for that

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't know about such limits

Comment: Alternatively, you can open this site https://webglreport.com/ on different devices to see their WebGL capabilities. You'll see that mobile devices have a smaller max texture size than, say, MacBooks or computers with a dedicated graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

So you can find out what the maximum size of the device supports

> var gl = document.getElementById( "my-canvas").getContext(
>   "experimental-webgl" ); alert(gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE))

the texture can be divided and applied in parts

Comment: yeah, well, In fact, I wasn't aware existence of such limits. Now everything is clear